# WSS_Logging database size

Tags: 2010, database, capacity-planning, farm-setup

Our sharepoint server 2010 WSS_Logging database is about 100GB and counting ...
(Farm DB ~1TB / ~100 000 pages viewed per day / ~5000 unique users per days)

I've reduced

- retention and logging levels for all services (through the central sharepoint admin for logging files) to 6 days
- Logging/Usage consolidation to 6 days (through powershell)

I assume this is usage data collection which take the more place, but these data are also used for Web Analytics

Is there any scenario for "large" sharepoint farm & usage data management ? I can't find reference/white paper on this topic.

Answer (score 2):

These guidance posts may be helpful as scenarios can vary  -

- [5 Best Practices to Configure Diagnostic Logging with PowerShell Commands](http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/sharepoint-2010/archive/2011/01/12/sharepoint-2010-cookbook-configure-diagnostic-logging-best-practices.aspx)
- [Best practices for operational excellence](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc850692.aspx)
- [Best practices for capacity management](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh403882.aspx)

UPDATE:
 Usage logging databases require ongoing maintenance. You can plan on how it's going to be used by selecting the tracing variables and other parameters and also by periodic clean-up tasks (archiving) using PowerShell or other utilities. There's a [Sharepoint 2010 Capacity Planning and Sizing Tool](http://tihomirignatov.blogspot.com/2010/12/sharepoint-2010-capacity-planning-and.html) that can be helpful in gauging your deployment.

Comment: I've already followed most of the advices regarding the WSS_Logging database which I can find in your link. The extra advice is to relocate the WSS_Logging but it has a cost (our SQL servers are managed by external provider). Moreover this solution do not fix the primary problem which is database size, and not overall farm performance.

Comment: I posted an update to my response above.